# How do i separate a video into frames without displaying all the frames in different figures?

Tags: matlab, figure, videodisplay

I have a code that takes a video and separate it into frames.I would like to NOT keep all the frames, instead i want each frame to be displayed in the previous figure.
The code looks like these:

```
 filename = uigetfile; %get the file name
obj = VideoReader(filename);
nFrames=obj.NumberOfFrames;
 for k = 1 : nFrames  
this_frame = read(obj, k);
thisfig = figure();
thisax = axes('Parent', thisfig);
image(this_frame, 'Parent', thisax);
title(thisax, sprintf('Frame #%d', k));
```

Another thing that's important is that i calculate intensities from each figure as it comes but i don't need to save the figure after i save the data.
Can anyone help me and tell me what i should change in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: can you maybe sketch out what you want as an illustration?

Comment: I don't understand you,sorry. Can you explain me what do you mean?

Comment: I think he is just trying to show all images sequentially without opening a new figure each time.

Comment: so he wants all the images side-by-side in one figure?

Comment: I have a video for example of 165 frames, every time i run my code i get 165 different figures with all the 165 frames. I would like that each frame will run over the previous frame.

Comment: Not side by side. At the end i want to have 1 figure with the title of which number of frame it is and it will display only the last frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it is a full solution, but one improvement in your code would definately be to move the `figure()` command out of the loop.

Maybe this is already sufficient, or maybe you need to assign your image command to a [handle](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/image.html) as described in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419209/in-matlab-how-does-one-clear-the-last-thing-plotted-to-a-figure) , allowing you to remove the last plotted image before you plot a new one.

Comment: When i take it outside of the loop i get only one figure at the end but it's not the last one and the title and the numbers on the axes are blurry.

Comment: @Maayan Thanks for accepting my answer. However, to help future visitors even more, I would like to ask you to post the final solution that you have found.

Answer (score 1):

```
    filename = uigetfile; %get the file name
    obj = VideoReader(filename);
    nFrames=obj.NumberOfFrames;
    thisfig = figure();
 for k = 1 : nFrames  
    this_frame = read(obj, k);
    thisax = axes('Parent', thisfig);
    image(this_frame, 'Parent', thisax);
    if k==nFrames
    title(thisax, sprintf('Frame #%d', k));
    end
end
```